# Database table for global settings

Tags: database-design

I am designing a database for a web application and would like to have a table for configurable global settings. Is there any established best practice for the design of this table? I can conceive of two possible solutions, and I'm sure there must be others.

The simplest would be just storing key/value pairs in there as strings. This would only take two columns, but would not give me any ability to add type constraints to individual items.

The other approach would be to add a column for every setting, but then the entire table would only have one row, and that feels a little odd.

How is this handled in most cases any of you have dealt with?

Comment: What platform are you using? It may be best to use platform-specific facilities for handling configuration.

Comment: Currently working with a simple php/mysql setup.

Comment: I'm also not dead set on using the database. If there is a good non database solution, which it seems there are, I am more than open to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What we use at my current project is a System Paramaters table called SYSPARMS.  This table is mainly a key/value table.  It uses a VARCHAR for both the key and value.  This allows us to specify the key in any form as well as the value (which really translates to the action).

I like using the DB because we can make real time adjustments that effect the applications.  For example, we have a value in there we set when the system is down for maintenance so no users can access the the web app.  We can at any time turn this off or on without having to deploy any apps.

Comment: I second the motion.  The key and value columns can be strings.  If you want to define the datatypes, you can do what Andrew Siemer suggestions and break things down further.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a database table to store application settings in the past and it's been very useful. Although, I do agree with your concern, that it feels like there should be a better way to do this. But, I don't know of it, so here we go:

1. Use rows to add settings, not columns. It's very easy to think "I will never need more settings than these" but you will, and it will become a giant, horrible mess. I've seen it.
2. Your Colums should be something like:

   - id - int
   - name - varchar(50)
   - value - text
   - data_type - varchar(50)
   - description - text
3. The id will come in handy for displaying your settings in an application loop, and is just good practice.
4. If possible make 'name' a unique column.
5. The 'text' datatype conforms to your data, so where varchar(50) sets aside 50 characters for each row no matter what, text will adjust according to how much data is there. If your data is something simple like a on or off switch, it can be one byte, if it's a long piece of copy, it can facilitate that without forcing the smaller data to be the same size. (I think this is how it works, although the minimum size may be larger than one byte - either way, something that adapts rather than conforms to a pre-defined amount is definitely a plus).
6. data_type: this is not required, but it sounds like you want a way to restrict what type of data may be entered for each setting. This is one of the drawbacks to the row paradigm: the datatype is merely a suggestion. This is more useful if you're planning to have an administration tool where admins are casuals and may enter bad data, then you can use this to check the proposed value before submitting it to the table and possibly crashing your application. Of course this will not do anything if everyone has direct access to the table, but it can be a useful guideline for that also.
7. description: these are comments. Use this to tell those who will come after you WHY you did what you did, and how to avoid crashing the application.

Answer (score 1):

The way settings are saved in [merb](http://merbivore.com) (and probably rails) is as key/value pairs, but not in a database table, rather in a [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) file, which has the advantage of being both human-readable and easily parse-able.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I like to do this if I am to do it in the database is to store attributes.  An attribute has a key/value pair.  But it also has an attribute type (which points to attributeTypes table) such as logging, siteConfig, externalReferences, ...what ever.  Then you can also have a table at the AttributeType level that specifies the datatype that is to be held in the attributes table.  DataTypeID would be stored with AttributeTypes.  This then points to a DataTypes table for lookup reasons.  This then allows you to know that you are working with numbers, dates, strings, xml, etc.  I find that this offers the most flexibility...if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net you can store global configuration values in the Web.Config file in Name/Value pairs.

Comment: similar to my answer but he wanted a "database", not just a config file.

Comment: @djangofan, he did mention he wanted a "database", but the question we, as responsible answerer's, is "do you really need a database table? can you get away with a config file?"

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework uses a config.ini and has a great parser that splits and forks the keys into arrays and subarrays depending on dot notation. The config.ini can be loaded as an instance and stored in the registry.

example:

db.name 'myname'

db.host 'myhost'

db.user 'myuser'

db.password 'mypassword'

I can now get these values like:

$config->db->name; or the full array $config->db;

Answer (score 0):

If there's only going to be one row in the table, then why use a database? Store the configuration, in XML, in a file.

If you still need to use a database, then store the configuration, in XML, in a column in the one row of the one table of the database.

Comment: Surely you're joking? What's the point of sticking your XML into database? How is that going to make things easier then key / value table?

Comment: you can add some form of type safety in the XML by using <connectionString type="string">...</connectionstring> or <maxLoginAttempts type="int">3</maxLoginAttempts>

Comment: @ChssPly76: Note I suggested keeping it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I like the YAML approach that STAii advocates.

If this a .NET or Java application you can also consider XML and use serialization to get at instances of your user settings conveniently.